# For loop within function to generate subsets of dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I am attempting to write a function which accepts a dataframe, and then generates subset dataframes within a for() loop.  As a first step, I tried the following:

```
dfcreator<-function(X,Z){
  for(i in 1:Z){
  df<-subset(X,Stratum==Z)    #build dataframe from observations where index=value
  assign(paste0("pop", Z),df) #name dataframe
 }
}
```

This however does not save anything in to memory, and when I try to specify a return() I am still not getting what I need.  For reference, I am using the
Sweden data set (which is native to RStudio).

**EDIT Per Melissa's Advice!**

I tried to implement the following code:

```
sampler <- function(df, n,...) {
  return(df[sample(nrow(df),n),])
}

sample_list<-map2(data_list, stratumSizeVec, sampler)
```

where stratumSizeVec is a 1X7 df and data_list is a list of seven dfs.  When I do this, I get seven samples in sample list all of the same size equal to stratumSizeVec[1].  Why is map2 not inputting the in the following manner

```
sampler(data_list$pop0,stratumSizeVec[1])
sampler(data_list$pop1,stratumSizeVec[2])
```

...

```
sampler(data_list$pop6,stratumSizeVec[7])
```

Furthermore, is there a way to "nest" the map2 function within lapply?

Comment: Creating a bunch of variables like this makes them much harder to work with in the long run. Better to use something like `split()` to create a list of data.frames. This will make many functions in R much happier. Variables created in function will not exist outside that function. Better to write functions that return values as a proper functional language should. Again, it make things much easier in the long run.

Comment: list2env(setNames(split(X,X$Stratum),paste0("pop",unique(X$Stratum))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you never actually utilize `i` anywhere in your loop.  It looks like you're creating `Z` copies of the data set where `Stratum == Z` - is that what you are after?

as for your code, I would use the following:

```
data_list <- split(df, df$Stratum)
names(data_list) <- paste0("pop", sort(unique(df$Stratum)))
```

This doesn't define a function, we are calling base-R function (namely `split`) which splits up a data frame based on some vector (here, we use `df$Stratum`).  The result is a list of data frames, each with a single value of `Stratum`.

#### Random sampling from rows

```
sampled_data <- lapply(data_list, function(df, n,...) { # n is the number of rows to take, the dots let you send other information to the `sample` function.
  df[sample(nrow(df), n, ...),]
},
n = 5,
replace = FALSE # this is default, but the purpose of using the ... notation is to allow this (and any other options in the `sample` function) to be changed.
)
```

You can also define the function separately:

```
sampler <- function(df, n,...) {
  df[sample(nrow(df), n, ...),]
}
sampled_data <- lapply(data_list, sampler, n = 10) # replace 10 with however many samples you want.
```

#### purrr:map2 method

As defined, the `sampler` function does not need to be modified, each element of the first list (data_list) is put into the first argument of sampler, and the corresponding element of the 2nd "list" (sampleSizeVec) is put into the 2nd argument.

```
library(purrr)
map2(data_list, sampleSizeVec, sampler, replace = FALSE) # replace = FALSE not needed, there as an example only.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Melissa! So using the split() function above, I make a list of my dataframes (one for each stratum).  Could I then use lapply to sample() each dataframe? The reason why I am attempting to include an index is because I need to access an element from a sample size vector using something like the following:  **samp1<-as.data.frame(sample(pop1$Sample.id ,StrataData$SampleSizeVec[i]))** where i is the index of the sample size vector.  Ultimately, I would like to have the following: **lapply(data_list, sample())**

Comment: try `lapply(data_list, sample)`

Comment: Thank you again, Melissa. When I do `sample_list<-lapply(data_list, sample, size=strata_data$nh,replace=FALSE)`  I get "samples" equal to the `data_list` above. How can I access the correct size from the `strata_data` dataframe? For instance, I need `strata_data$nh[1]` for the first sample and  `strata_data$nh[2]` for the second sample.

Comment: Thank you! So you are saying I should write a function `sampler` which takes the dataframe `pop1` as an input as well as the vector `strata_data$nh[1]` then takes the correct sample, and then  have `sample_data<-lapply(data_list,sampler)` ?  ---------I just saw you edit - thank you, I will look at it now!

Comment: So just to clarify: in your edited code,`function(df,n,...)` is a function which takes n samples from each dataframe in `data_list`? What exactly is `indices`? Thank you for all of your follow-ups!

Comment: sorry, crazy day for me.  bugs fixed. :)  (hopefully no new ones added)

Comment: Thank you so much - please don't apologize - I still can't believe people like you help random people on the internet haha.  This is exactly what I was looking for, but I just want `n` to be a vector. To flesh this out: if I have a 1X6 vector 'sampleSizeVec` of stratum sizes {10,5,2,3,5,8} I want to be able to get a sample size of 10 for the first sample, 5 for the second sample, and 8 for the sixth sample.  Is this a case where I should use like a nested `lapply(data_list,sampler,sapply(sampleSizeVec, seq_along))`?

Comment: Thank you again, Melissa! Coming from python, I have been trying to familiarize myself with the `apply` family - but it seems weird that it is so hard to index things within loops.  Anyways, thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know python well, but the trick with loops in R is to use vectorized code instead.  that basically means working with functions which have the loops internalized in compiled code.  I would recommend R for data science by Hadley Wickham (http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) if you're looking for a good resource on learning R.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help Melissa! I looked at the Wickham and it seems fantastic.  The map2 still isn't quite working (per my edit in the original question)...Any advice?

Comment: `map2` is an alternative to `lapply` - they both serve the same general purpose.  There is no reason to nest one in the other.  `stratumSizeVec` should be a vector, not a data frame.  It will fail if you put the vector in a data frame.